# Implementing a usb interface for ATtiny816 microcontrollers

Tags: c, assembly, avr, avr-gcc, avrdude

I am trying to receive and send some data from a computer to an ATtiny816 through USB. Can an ATtiny816 microcontroller communicate with a computer through USB? If yes, how should it be connected?

Comment: This will probably soon be closed for bot actually being a programming question. BUut the way to connect a USB to any microcontroller with a serial port is using a serial-USB converter.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if this is possible. ATtiny 816 don't have hardware USB so you have to write software stack by yourself. Take a look on [V-USB library](https://www.obdev.at/products/vusb/index.html) for AVR chips. It's software USB stack for most of AVR chips.

I have second idea, but question is for what you need USB? If you want to parse some commands from computer you may use USB-UART converter and parse commands from UART interface.

Comment: Not even the ATMega328P (Used in the Arduino Uno/Nano) has a USB hardware yet you can plug the Arduino to the USB. Just use an USB-to-serial chip :)

Comment: That's why I have wrote about USB-UART converter. But this is another chip in system. Sometime it's not possible to add another hardware. Second solution is V-USB library.

Comment: Oh, I stopped at "for what you need USB?", sorry :) That's good advice anyway.